# cant get 2nd datatable its own css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables

I am trying to get my second datatable to use its own css (for the alternating row color) once i added the {  sClass: "myCustomClass" }, my jquery is not firing anymore.

Css for the demo_table.css

```
/* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
* DataTables row classes
*/
table.display tr.odd.gradeA {
background-color: #ddffdd;
}

table.display tr.even.gradeA {
background-color: #eeffee;
}

table.display tr.odd.gradeC {
background-color: #ddddff; 
}

table.display tr.even.gradeC {
background-color: #eeeeff;
}

table.display tr.odd.gradeX {
background-color: #ffdddd;
}

table.display tr.even.gradeX {
background-color: #ffeeee;
}

table.display tr.odd.gradeU {
background-color: #ddd;
}

table.display tr.even.gradeU {
background-color: #eee;
}


tr.odd {
background-color: #E2E4FF;
}

tr.even {
background-color: white;
}

table.display tr.even.myCustomClass { background-color: #FFFFCC; }
table.display tr.odd.myCustomClass { background-color: #ffeeee; }
```

Jquery I am using to initialize the datatable, which worked perfectly before adding the sclass in but didnt have any of the css that i added.

```
    function nestedtable(systemid) {
    var dbselected = $('#dblist').find(":selected").text();

    $('#nested_id').dataTable({
        "sAjaxSource": '/php/connect/nestedsearchtablequery.php',
        "bProcessing": true,
        "bDeferRender": true,
        "bDestroy": true,
        "sAjaxDataProp": "",
        "fnServerParams": function (aoData) {
            aoData.push({ "name": "db", "value": dbselected}),
            aoData.push({ "name": "systemid", "value": systemid });
        },
        "aoColumns": [
            {  sClass: "myCustomClass" }, 
            { "mData": "eventtime" },
            { "mData": "eventtype" },
            { "mData": "cid_name" },
            { "mData": "cid_num" },
            { "mData": "cid_ani" },
            { "mData": "cid_dnid" },
            { "mData": "exten" },
            { "mData": "context" },
            { "mData": "appname" },
            { "mData": "channame" }, ]
        //"bJQueryUI": true  //This is commented out to remove the smooth datatable style
    });
}
```

I have two tables #table_id and #nested_id, I am trying to change row colors on #nested_id.

This is the jquery for the #nested_id

```
 function fnFormatDetails(oTable, nTr, systemid) {

    var sOut =
'<div class="innerDetails">' +
  '<table id="nested_id" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="padding-left:50px; background:white;">' +
    '<thead>'
                 + '<tr>'
                     + '<th>Time</th>'
                     + '<th>Event</th>'
                     + '<th>CNAM</th>'
                     + '<th>CNUM</th>'
                     + '<th>ANI</th>'
                     + '<th>DID</th>'
                     + '<th>Exten</th>'
                     + '<th>Context</th>'
                     + '<th>AppName</th>'
                     + '<th>Channel</th>'
                 + '</tr>'
             + '</thead>'
             + '<tbody></tbody>'
    '</table>' +
'</div>';
    return sOut;
}
```

This is the html for the #table_id

```
    <body>
    <div id="stable" style=" margin-left: 2%; margin-right: 2%; display: none">
        <table class="display" id="table_id">
             <thead>
                 <tr>
                     <th>Call Date</th>
                     <th>Recording</th>
                     <th>System</th>
                     <th>CallerID</th>
                     <th>App</th>
                     <th>Destination</th>
                     <th>Disposition</th>
                     <th>Duration</th>          
                 </tr>
             </thead>
             <tbody></tbody>    
        </table>
    </div>           
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is in your CSS...  `sClass` puts the class on every `td` in a column, not a `tr`.  So `tr.even.myCustomClass` is never applied.

It should be more like:

```
table.display tr.even td.myCustomClass { background-color: #FFFFCC; }
table.display tr.odd td.myCustomClass { background-color: #ffeeee; }
```

**EDIT** based on update to OP

You can avoid using sClass all together, and just use CSS specific to your nested table:

Your table in your html is missing `class="display"`.  So you can either add and you CSS is:

```
table.display#nested_id tr.even { background-color: #FFFFCC; }
table.display#nested_id tr.odd { background-color: #ffeeee; }
```

Or you can leave it off and your CSS is:

```
table#nested_id tr.even { background-color: #FFFFCC; }
table#nested_id tr.odd { background-color: #ffeeee; }
```

Finally, you'll need to add CSS for

```
table#nested_id tr.even .sorting_1{ /*background-color here*/ }
table#nested_id tr.odd .sorting_1{ /*background-color here*/ }
```

See this [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/guydog28/8mnBf/) for a working example.

Comment: What way would i be able to just do a row color then ? And by changing that the colors do not get applied still.

Comment: Even after adding that the colors do not change. hmmm im puzzled lol.

Comment: can you add the HTML code (even if there is no data) to your post that you are trying to style?  That will help immensely to see the structure of the HTML we are styling.

Comment: Even after fixing the css and adding the display class mirroring what you have on jsfiidle, something must be overriding it because the colors are still the same as default.

Comment: if you need i can provide a site you can look at with a account.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37744/discussion-between-guydog28-and-user1552172)